# Firebase functions - is it possible to deploy functions:config variables without depoying all the functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have added a new environment variable to the functions:config.
I have some cloud functions that are not ready to be deployed to production yet.

How can I deploy the env variable without deploying all the functions?

It tells me to use:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible.  The functions config env vars are essentially part of each individual function's deployment.  They don't exist separately from the function - they **are** part of the function and are packaged up along with it when you deploy.

To put it another way, you can think of the vars as part of the code of your function.  If you change the code or vars at all, the entire thing needs to be redeployed.

Comment: so just to clarify you can't update the env vars just for a single function if you just deploy that function? It has to be all or nothing?

Comment: Yes, you have to deploy the entire function again in order to see a change in the vars.

Comment: function or functions? Sorry just trying to clarify. Can you just deploy one function and then only that single function has access to the new config vars?

Comment: Please review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions) to learn about how to deploy functions individually. Each individual deployment uses the vars currently configured at the time of deployment for only the functions deployed.

Comment: To be clear, each function is completely isolated from all other functions. It doesn't matter if they were deployed at the same time from the same codebase.  Each one has its own copy of code and config that can't be modified except by deploying the function again.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Understood. I do normally only deploy individual functions. That actually solves my problem as it means I can deploy just the functions I need that use the new variable in the config. I can't see where this is in the docs though.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this it actually appears "environment variables" are now recommended over "environment configuration" https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#environment_configuration

Comment: It's not in the documentation.  If you have feedback about the docs, use the "send feedback" button at the top of the page.